# Django-allauth loads wrong base.html template

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I've been trying to get django-allauth working for a couple days now and I finally found out what was going on.

Instead of loading the `base.html` template that installs with django-allauth, the app loads the `base.html` file that I use for the rest of my website.

How do i tell django-allauth to use the base.html template in the `virtualenv/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django-allauth` directory instead of my `project/template` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless called directly, your `base.html` is an extension of the templates that you define.

For example, if you render a template called `Page.html` - at the top you will have `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

When defined as above, `base.html` is located in the path that you defined in your `settings.py` under `TEMPLATE_DIRS = ()` - which, from your description, is defined as `project/template`.

Your best bet is to copy the django-allauth `base.html` file to the defined `TEMPLATE_DIRS` location, rename it to `allauthbase.html`, then extend your templates to include it instead of your default base via `{% extends "allauthbase.html" %}`.

Alternatively you could add a subfolder to your template location like `project/template/allauth`, place the allauth `base.html` there, and then use `{% extends "allauth/base.html" %}`.

Answer (score 9):

I had the opposite problem: I was trying to use my own `base.html` file, but my Django project was grabbing the `django-allauth` version of `base.html`. It turns out that the order you define `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` affects how templates are rendered. In order to have **my** `base.html` render instead of the one defined in `django-allauth`, I needed to define `INSTALLED_APPS` as the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # custom
    'common',
    'users',
    'app',
    # allauth
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: I could kiss you. You saved me from basically abandoning allauth!

Answer (score 3):

Two years later this continues to be a problem and the accepted answer is missing some new information.

On [github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/370) I discovered that all allauth templates derive from account/base.html, which derives from base.html. My solution was:

- In `virtualenv/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django-allauth/templates`, copy the entire contents of `base.html` to replace everything in `account/base.html` (i.e. replace the `{% extends 'base.html' %}` statement)
- Delete allauth's `base.html`. It is now redundant.

Done!

Comment: True. I didn't understand such things at the time

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers provided force you to rewrite files and modify your own project to fit in with allauth, which is a completely unacceptable workflow.  Such a third-party application should not have such manipulative power over your own project.

Truly, the easiest way to handle this situation, especially based on the answers provided, is to simply move the allauth app and its associated apps to the end of your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py` file.  Django will find your `base.html` template before it finds the other `base.html` template in the other apps listed beneath it.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

`django-allauth` templates seem to extend `account/base.html` ([example](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html)), which extends `base.html`.

So copy [`base.html`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/base.html) to for example `myapp/templates/account/base.html`, and make sure that `myapp` loads before `django-allauth` (by putting it higher in `INSTALLED_APPS`).

Now the django auth templates will extend your `account/base.html`, which will be `django-allauth`'s `base.html`.

It's not perfect, since `django-allauth`'s `base.html` might update and you'll miss those updates. But it seems better than renaming all your imports or changing `django-allauth` code.

Note that you can also just put a `{% block content %}` in your `base.html` around the content, and then `django-allauth` will use that style, which seems like a good thing in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

`Allauth` tries to extend `myproject/templates/base.html`. The easiest ways are to move `base.html` to `myproject/templates/site/` in order to get  `myproject/templates/site/base.html` or simply rename `base.html`